# How Laravel anonymous function know it's parameter

Tags: php, laravel, anonymous-function

Consider this code:

```
$fn = FormNilai::whereHas('mataPelajaranLokalGuru',function($mlg) {
      $mlg->where('guru_id','=',$this->uid);
})->get();
```

How is `$mlg` always treated as `FormNilai` instance? how is the scenario? I read a lot about dependency injection but still don't get the point.

Comment: This is not dependency injection, and `$mlg` is a `Query` instance and not a `FormNilai` instance. You need to read the documentation, in particular [Querying relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `$mlg` isn't treated as `FormNilai` instance, it's just treated as an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

You can see that how it works in the source codes.
[Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L934](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L934)

#### Example:

Define an anonymous function accepts an regular argument:

```
$example = function ($arg) {
    var_dump($arg);
};

$example("hello");
```

You can change the argument name to any string, just like `$myArgument`.
And the the output would not been changed whatever the argument name is.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, but i just wonder how $mlg always treated as Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder even we change the variable name, whatever the variable name

Comment: The variable name depends on your defined. You must remember the anonymous function is defined by yourself. And the parameter will pass to the anonymous function while it is called.

Comment: can you explain with a sippet?

Answer (score 1):

[Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection) is a different part. As per your code example, You need to the tell the anonymous function to use that variable like...

```
$uid = $this->uid; 
$fn = FormNilai::whereHas('mataPelajaranLokalGuru',function($mlg) use($uid)
                    {
                        $mlg->where('guru_id','=',$uid);
                    })->get();
```

As that variable `uid` is outside the scope of the anonymous function it needs to be passed in using the use keyword as shown in the above code.

You can get more idea on  `use` with example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-200)

Answer (score 0):

Laterally i've realize that laravel support php anonymous style so we can implement such a javascript function usage but surely it hard for me to do for first time

For simple usage, they display an example like this

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
$query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
}))->get();
```

What if the user wanted to make the third parameter is filled with variable. When i check it out with replacing those '%first%' word with any global variable, it ruins the structure, and it happend to me.

```
$title = 'heirlom of marineford';
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
   $query->where('title', 'like', $title);
}))->get();
```

After searching to PHP documentation, i found that the technique to passing parameter to that anonymous function by extending function block with use() so the function would assume to use all variable that defined by the use() section

```
$title = 'heirlom of marineford';
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query) use($title)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', $title);
}))->get();
```

I hope that could help you